# Problem over prime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers

Which is the largest integer $n<1000$ so that $n$,  $n+2$  and $n+4$ are primes?

I have tried to solve this problem but have not reached an argument worth

Comment: Think about divisibility by $3$.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the letter y between $n+2$ and $n+4$ means the same thing as "and" in English, so I edited that in.

Answer (score 8):

n = 3, because for any larger n, one of them is divisible by 3.

Comment: Unless $n=-7$ counts as "larger" and negative primes count  :).

Comment: @ErickWong: It makes no difference. They were asking for the *largest* integer. Even if we consider largeness in terms of absolute value, and even if we consider negative primes, the answer is still $3$.

Comment: @CameronBuie Care to check again?

Comment: @ErickWong: /facepalm/ Huh. Yep. $7$ is bigger than $3$. I give up for the night.

Answer (score 2):

Observe the following. If $n$ is prime, let it be $1$ mod $3$. Then $n+2$ will be divisible by $3$. If it is $2$ mod $3$, $n+4$ will be divisible by $3$. Therefore the only solution is if $n=3$. i.e.  $3,5,7$ is the sequence you are after.

Comment: In fact, you can get rid of $n<1000$